# CSS issue with changing colors on hover / clicked

Tags: javascript, css

```js
 var $ = function (id) { return document.getElementById(id); };
 
 function generatealtartiles() {
        for (let i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.id = "at" + i;
            div.addEventListener("click", function () { buildaltar(i) });
            $("altartiles").appendChild(div);
        }
    }

    function buildaltar(tilenumber) {
            var tileId = "a" + tilenumber;
            $("altartiles").className = "red";
            $(tileId).style.borderColor = "#fff";
            }
```

```css
    #altartiles {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 10px;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 34px 34px 34px;
        grid-template-rows: 63px 63px;
        grid-gap: 8px 6px;
    }
    #altartiles > div {
        background-color: #000;
        border: 2px dashed red;
    }
    #altartiles > div:hover {
        border-color: #fff;
    }
    .red > div {
        border: 2px dashed red;
        border-color: red;
    }
    .red > div:hover {
        border-color: #fff;
    }
```

```html
      <body onload="generatealtartiles()">
      <div id="altartiles"></div>
      </body>
```

EDIT - I added a snippet but it gives an error when I click on one of the divs that I don't get when running this locally on my machine.  When I run it locally the div border does turn white.  It just stays white and won't turn back red unless I specifically turn it back to red by its ID.  If I do that though it won't turn white on hover anymore.

Comment: have you set `border:1px solid` first if border weight is not set then color will not reflect. if possible create code snippet.

Comment: Yes I do have it set first!  I updated my post to reflect that.

Comment: if you can give full code snippet by using stackoverflow snippet option. it will more easy to help out.

Comment: sorry I don't see the snippet option anywhere?

Comment: https://ibb.co/SJ0sMPG see this screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the `:active` decorator instead of adding/removing classes?

```
.parentDiv > div {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
.parentDiv > div:hover, div:active {
    border-color: white;
}
```

---

Update after seeing snippet:

```js
var $ = function (id) { return document.getElementById(id); };

function generatealtartiles() {
  for (let i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
      var div = document.createElement('div');
      div.id = "a" + i;
      div.onclick = function() {
        resetTiles();
        this.style.borderColor = 'white';
      }
      $("altartiles").appendChild(div);
  }
}

function resetTiles(){
  for (let i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
    $("a" + i).style.borderColor = '';
  }
}
```

```css
#altartiles {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 34px 34px 34px;
    grid-template-rows: 63px 63px;
    grid-gap: 8px 6px;
}
#altartiles > div {
    background-color: #000;
    border: 2px dashed red;
}
#altartiles > div:hover {
    border-color: white;
}
```

```html
<body onload="generatealtartiles()">
<div id="altartiles"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Looking forward to a code snippet then. You can also keep going with what you've got, but add an onBlur() event function to your divs which can set the color back.

Comment: added the snippet.  It returns an error though that I don't get on my own machine.. not sure why.

Comment: YES!  Thank you!!!  Totally didn't think to just remove the border completely then add it again..